# retrieve body of json from api

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to return the quote section from this api located here: https://api.quotable.io/random

The json looks like this:

> {"_id":"9hIehvX23pvr","content":"There is no charm equal to tenderness
>   of heart.","author":"Jane Austen"}

Here is the part of the code that connects to the API.

```
Future<String> _getQuote() async {
  final res = await http.get('https://api.quotable.io/random');
  return json.decode(res.body);
}
```

Whenever I run the app, I get this error that tells me it's getting a null.  But I know the api works.

> _FutureBuilderState#b8df9): I/flutter ( 5315): A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget. I/flutter ( 5315):
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': I/flutter ( 5315): Failed
>   assertion: line 269 pos 10: 'data != null'

I just need the "content" part of the json.  How would I parse just that part?

Thanks!

Comment: print(res) output here in your question, you know your API is working but clearly the response is null

Answer (score 0):

@SkyeBoniwell, not getting any response with the api. Sure it's working?

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I just tried a `GET` in Postman and got data, could it have been down momentarily?

Comment: you need to pass proper headers to get a response. It returns a random quote, just open the URL in your browser.

Comment: @chrisbyte hmm..for some reason, i am still getting the same error in Postman. Def smthg wrong with the api.

Comment: yes, it's working fine at my end. Might be API issue. That's why you must always check http response status prior to response content parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step1 : add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to `AndroidManifest` 
Step2 : Use the following class to parse

```
Demo demoFromJson(String str) => Demo.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String demoToJson(Demo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Demo {
  String id;
  String content;
  String author;

  Demo({
    this.id,
    this.content,
    this.author,
  });

  factory Demo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Demo(
        id: json["_id"],
        content: json["content"],
        author: json["author"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "content": content,
        "author": author,
      };
}
```

working demo

[image]

full working code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

Demo demoFromJson(String str) => Demo.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String demoToJson(Demo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Demo {
  String id;
  String content;
  String author;

  Demo({
    this.id,
    this.content,
    this.author,
  });

  factory Demo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Demo(
        id: json["_id"],
        content: json["content"],
        author: json["author"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "content": content,
        "author": author,
      };
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilderWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

String url = ' http://api.quotable.io/random';

///Method for GET Request
Future<Demo> getDemoResponse() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://api.quotable.io/random');
  print('response ${response}');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('response body${response.body}');
    return demoFromJson(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load ');
  }
}

class FutureBuilderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FutureBuilderWidgetState createState() => _FutureBuilderWidgetState();
}

class _FutureBuilderWidgetState extends State<FutureBuilderWidget> {
  bool _isButtonClicked = false;
  var _buttonIcon = Icons.cloud_download;
  var _buttonText = "Fetch Data";
  var _buttonColor = Colors.green;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Future Builder Widget',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                //fontFamily: Utils.ubuntuRegularFont
              ),
            ),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 48),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Demo>(
          ///If future is null then API will not be called as soon as the screen
          ///loads. This can be used to make this Future Builder dependent
          ///on a button click.
          future: _isButtonClicked ? getDemoResponse() : null,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {

              ///when the future is null
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Text(
                  'Press the button to fetch data',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                );

              case ConnectionState.active:

              ///when data is being fetched
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue));

              case ConnectionState.done:

                ///task is complete with an error (eg. When you
                ///are offline)
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return Text(
                    'Error:\n\n${snapshot.error}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  );

                ///task is complete with some data
                return Text(
                  'Fetched Data:\n\n${snapshot.data.content}',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        backgroundColor: _buttonColor,
        onPressed: () {
          ///Calling method to fetch data from the server
          //getDemoResponse();

          ///You need to reset UI by calling setState.
          setState(() {
            _isButtonClicked == false
                ? _isButtonClicked = true
                : _isButtonClicked = false;

            if (!_isButtonClicked) {
              _buttonIcon = Icons.cloud_download;
              _buttonColor = Colors.green;
              _buttonText = "Fetch Data";
            } else {
              _buttonIcon = Icons.replay;
              _buttonColor = Colors.deepOrange;
              _buttonText = "Reset";
            }
          });
        },
        icon: Icon(
          _buttonIcon,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        label: Text(
          _buttonText,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```